# How can I create a list, where at the end of each item on the list, there is a colored square?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have, but the boxes are going before the text, need them after

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Red<span class="box red"></span></li>
  <li>Green<span class="box green"></span></li>
  <li>Blue<span class="box blue"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why not add them as pseudo-elements?

Comment: `li {
    clear: left;
}`

Answer (score 1):

[Floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) are troublesome and usually an outdated approach. Don't use them unless you know why. Here they were doing what a person would expect when set to `left`, which is to shift their elements to the left side of their containing element.

Also note that span elements are *inline*. This means they don't have size. Either use divs or set them to `inline-block`. The float effectively did that for you, but we need to do it ourselves now.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Red<span class="box red"></span></li>
  <li>Green<span class="box green"></span></li>
  <li>Blue<span class="box blue"></span></li>
</ul>
```